# Dataflow reading from PubSub works at GCP, can't run locally

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a small test Dataflow job that just reads from a PubSub subscription and discards the message, that we're using to start some proof-of-concept work.

It works just fine running at GCP, but fails locally.  My expectation is that the same code should work either way, just by switching the Dataflow runner, but perhaps that's not the case?  Here's the code:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import logging

from apache_beam import Map, io, Pipeline
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

def noop(element):
    pass

def run(input_subscription, pipeline_args=None):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        pipeline_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True
    )

    with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        (
            pipeline
            | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription, with_attributes=True)
            | "noop" >> Map(noop)
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    run(
        os.environ['INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION'],
        [
            '--runner', os.getenv('RUNNER', 'DirectRunner'),
            '--project', os.getenv('PROJECT'),
            '--region', os.getenv('REGION'),
            '--temp_location', os.getenv('TEMP_LOCATION'),
            '--service_account_email', os.getenv('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL'),
            '--network', os.getenv('NETWORK'),
            '--subnetwork', os.getenv('SUBNETWORK'),
            '--num_workers', os.getenv('NUM_WORKERS'),
        ]
    )
```

If I run it with this command line, it creates and runs the job in the Google Cloud just fine:

```
INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION=subscriptionname \
RUNNER=DataflowRunner \
PROJECT=project \
REGION=region \
TEMP_LOCATION=gs://somewhere/temp \
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL=serviceaccount@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
NETWORK=network \
SUBNETWORK=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project/regions/region/subnetworks/subnetwork \
NUM_WORKERS=3 \
python read-pubsub-with-dataflow.py
```

If I omit the `RUNNER` option, so it uses `DirectRunner`:

```
INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION=subscriptionname \
PROJECT=project \
REGION=region \
TEMP_LOCATION=gs://somewhere/temp \
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL=serviceaccount@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
NETWORK=network \
SUBNETWORK=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project/regions/region/subnetworks/subnetwork \
NUM_WORKERS=3 \
python read-pubsub-with-dataflow.py
```

it fails with a whole flood of error messages, but I'll just include the first one (I think the rest are just cascading):

```
INFO:apache_beam.runners.direct.direct_runner:Running pipeline with DirectRunner.
/Users/denis/redacted/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:70: UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK without a quota project. You might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. We recommend you rerun `gcloud auth application-default login` and make sure a quota project is added. Or you can use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
  warnings.warn(_CLOUD_SDK_CREDENTIALS_WARNING)
ERROR:apache_beam.runners.direct.executor:Exception at bundle <apache_beam.runners.direct.bundle_factory._Bundle object at 0x7fed3e368448>, due to an exception.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/denis/redacted/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/transform_evaluator.py", line 694, in _read_from_pubsub
    self._sub_name, max_messages=10, return_immediately=True)
  File "/Users/denis/redacted/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/_gapic.py", line 40, in <lambda>
    fx = lambda self, *a, **kw: wrapped_fx(self.api, *a, **kw)  # noqa
  File "/Users/denis/redacted/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/pubsub_v1/services/subscriber/client.py", line 1106, in pull
    "If the `request` argument is set, then none of "
ValueError: If the `request` argument is set, then none of the individual field arguments should be set.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...etc...
```

I suspect maybe this has to do with credentials?  Or our project config?  Perhaps I should try in a new blank project.

Comment: The error says it all, it's related to the credentials and how the pipelines authenticates with GCP. I recommend you to use a service account instead and give that service account all the needed permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be incompatible package versions.  My `requirements.txt` had been:

```
apache_beam[gcp]
google_apitools
google-cloud-pubsub
```

but that was installing a version of the `google-cloud-pubsub` package that was breaking `apache_beam`.  I changed my `requirements.txt` to:

```
apache_beam[gcp]
google_apitools
```

and it all works now!

And for what it's worth, running locally with `DirectRunner` I obviously did not need a lot of the options that I needed for `DataflowRunner`.  This sufficed:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/credentials.json \
RUNNER=DirectRunner \
INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION=projects/mytopic/subscriptions/mysubscription \
python read-pubsub-with-dataflow.py
```